# MySQL Temp Tables Having Trouble With Case Statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a temp table in MySQL 8.0 via the command prompt. The select statement correctly returns values on its own, but when it is placed into a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement, I get an error.

I've tried a number of things, from changing the syntax to other insert statements. Can't find a solution. Thanks to anyone who can assist.

```
create temporary table tempTable 
select game_date
,home_team
,inning
,inning_topbot
, 'innType'=case when   inning_topbot='top' then away_score   
   else home_score   
   end 
from pitchdata;
```

```
ERROR 1166 (42000): Incorrect column name ''innType'=case when   inning_topbot='top' then away_score   else home_score   end'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want.

Comment: ` ... , case when   inning_topbot='top' then away_score else home_score end as innType, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax doesn't make sense.  Perhaps this is what you intend:

```
create temporary table tempTable as
    select game_date, home_team, inning, inning_topbot, 
           (case when inning_topbot = 'top' then away_score
                 else home_score
            end) as innType
    from pitchdata;
```